# Epoch time .NET to JavaScript (hour off?)

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net, unix-timestamp

Using the following code in .NET

```
Input: "2011-09-14 00:00:00.0000000" (From an SQL datebase loaded into a Date datetype becoming #9/14/2011#)

<Extension()>
Public Function ToEpoch(value As Date) As Double
    Dim span As TimeSpan = (value - New Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime)
    Return span.TotalMilliseconds
End Function
```

And this in JavaScript

```
var StartDate = new Date(<%= StartDate() %>);
```

Resulting in this output

```
var StartDate = new Date(1315922400000);
```

It appears that only for this specific input the StartDate (on the javascript side) is exactly one hour off.

Resulting in the JavaScript datetime of: `Tue Sep 13 23:00:00 UTC+1000 2011`

If I input a value like `Date.Now` it appears to function correctly.

I assume I'm missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me that unix epoch is Jan 1, 1970, UTC.

In light of that, your creation of the Date and then conversion to local time is somewhat backwards. What you need to do is convert the variable time value to UTC.

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToEpoch(value As Date) As Double
    Dim span As TimeSpan = (value.ToUniversalTime - 
                                New System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc))
    Return span.TotalMilliseconds
End Function
```

You may think the two conversions are equivalent, but they may not be, as explained in
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/24/55413.aspx .

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the two dates have different daylight savings values.  See if the following calls to `IsDaylightSavingTime()` return the same values:

```
Dim dt As Date = new Date(2011, 9, 14)
Dim epoch As Date = new Date(1970, 1, 1)

dt.IsDaylightSavingTime()
epoch.IsDaylightSavingTime()
```